# Javascript - query params from window.location.href

Tags: javascript, string, parameters

I'm new to `Javascript` syntax; sorry if this is too basic.

With this query:

```
const params = queryString.parse(window.location.href)
```

I am fetching:

```
{http://localhost:3000/#access_token: "accessToken", refresh_token: "refreshToken"}
```

and now I can easily do:

```
const refresh_token = params.refresh_token;
```

But how do I fetch "accessToken"?

Comment: What is your `queryString`? The string there is *very* strange, consider fixing them to the standard format so they're parsable by URLSearchParams

Comment: usually I would get `queryString.parse(window.location.search)`, but this is a server to server to frontend operation, and `href` is all I'm being able to fetch from my backend server.

Comment: You should fix whatever constructs that URL so that it gives you standard search parameters instead.

Comment: no regex nor `substring()` can save me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the hash is malformed JSON. While it'd be parsable by adding a `{` to the left side, adding `"`s around word characters before a `:`, and `JSON.parse`-ing it:

```js
// const { hash } = window.location;
// const badJSON = '{' + hash.slice(1);
// now, you'll have:
const badJSON = '{' + 'access_token: "accessToken", refresh_token: "refreshToken"}';
const json = badJSON.replace(/\w+(?=:)/g, '"$&"');
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.access_token);
console.log(obj.refresh_token);
```

This is extremely awkward, and is a solution to an X/Y problem. It would be much better to fix whatever generates the URL so that its format is in the standard format so you can parse it with URLSearchParams. For example, the URL should be something like

```
http://localhost:3000/?access_token=accessToken&refresh_token=refreshToken
```

And then it can be parsed very easily:

```js
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/?access_token=accessToken&refresh_token=refreshToken';
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.match(/\?.*/)[0]);

// in your real code, the above can be replaced with:
// const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

console.log(params.get('access_token'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
getHashParams() {
    const hashParams = {};
    const r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g;
    const q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    let e = r.exec(q);
    while (e) {
      hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
      e = r.exec(q);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }
```

and calling like so:

```
const params = this.getHashParams();
console.log(params);
```

logged:

```
{access_token: "aceessToken", refresh_token: "refreshToken"}
```